# How do I get started in WebGL

Tags: webgl, html5-animation

How do I get started in programming WebGL

Comment: [Read](http://learningwebgl.com) [a](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Tutorial) [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL)?

Answer (score 4):

The lessons on this site are a fantastic introduction.  You should also pickup a reference guide on OpenGL ES 2.0 (the basis for webgl).

[learningwebgl](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217)